# Paypal express checkout : systematic 10486 error

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

i use paypal express checkout to sell simple benefit on my website.
When i am with sandbox, it works fine. But as soon as i change for live mode with real password and signature, i get systematically this error :

```
[ACK] => Failure
[VERSION] => 123.0
[BUILD] => 21463915
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10486
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => This transaction couldn't be completed
```

My buyer account is good and no problems to buy on other websites.
I asked friends to try with their own paypal account or Credit card and they get the same issue.

I must say that i checked my script again and again but no errors. Anyway, it works fine on an other website but with an other paypal account.

Has someone already encountered this problem?
thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Sorry, i wrote "hi all" but doesn't appear ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.
For those who find themselves in this situation, **check which category you opened your PayPal account**.
Indeed, some categories such as online meetings require additional special authorizations. In this case, your account will refuse all transactions...
Go figure why paypal does not inform you ...

Answer (score 0):

If the funding option selected by the buyer fails in a DoExpressCheckoutPayment or a DoAuthorization call, a funding failure recovery process is available to merchants. Error code 10486 is returned to merchants when a buyer's payment fails due to a bad funding method (typically an invalid or maxed out credit card). If the merchant receives this error code from PayPal, the Merchant can redirect the buyer back to the PayPal page to select an alternate payment source or to add a new funding instrument.

Possible reasons for payment failure include:

```
The billing address associated with the financial Instrument could not be confirmed.
The transaction exceeds the card limit.
The transaction was denied by the card issuer.
```

Reference link :

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/express-checkout/ht-ec-fundingfailure10486/

Comment: Indeed, I have traveled all internet forum and read paypal's doc for this error. Alas, none of the three reasons cited does not apply in my case.
I suscpect the problem come from business account (merchant) which is very  recent (72 hours).
I posted this issue directly to [link](https://paypal-techsupport.com) but for the time being, no answer.

Comment: please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36887028/create-paypal-sandbox-merchant-seller-account)

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**
PayPal returned API error code 10486 - This transaction couldn't be completed.

**Cause**
A buyer’s Express Checkout payment failed due to a bad funding source; for example, the transaction exceeded the buyer's card limit.

**Solution**
If you send your buyer to the PayPal page to select an alternate funding source or add a new funding source, this eliminates the need to perform another SetExpressCheckout call that reinitiates the entire transaction flow. It also helps the buyer to complete the transaction (instead of getting stuck in an endless checkout loop).